# How to check whether the url is of format "/askwiki/questions/<any number>" in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to learn web scraping using BeautifulSoup and Python.

I scraped a list of urls from a website and I want to display the text of all th links that are in format "/askwiki/questions/ like
"/askwiki/questions/4" or "/askwiki/questions/123".

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://unistd.herokuapp.com/askrec';

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml");

links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
    if #url is of my desired format
        print link.text
```

What should I write in the if statement.

I am new to python as well as web scraping. It may be a really stupid question but I am not getting what to write there.

I tried like

> if "/askwiki/questions/[0-9]+ " in link.get("href"):
>
> if "/askwiki/questions/[0-9]?" in link.get("href"):

but it's not working.

P.S - There are other links too like 'askwiki/questions/tags' and /askwiki/questions/users'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Using regex to identify only those with numbers at the end.

```
import re

for link in links:    
    url = str(link.get('href'))
    if re.findall('/askwiki/questions/[\d]+', url):
        print(link)
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not the case. There are other links too like ''/askwiki/questions/tags' or '/askwiki/questions/users'. @jack6e

Comment: And you only want the ones with '/#'?

Comment: Yes! I only want the ones with '/askwiki/questions/X'. X should only be a number of any digits. It should not be any other character other than 0-9.

Comment: File "first.py", line 15, in <module>
    if re.findall('/askrec/questions/[\d]+', s):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 181, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Sorry, it may be `url.text` that you need in the `re.findall()` statement. That `url` variable just needs to be a pure string, however you extract that from your BS object.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track! The missing component is the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

I think what you want is something like this:

```
import re
matcher = re.compile(r"/askwiki/questions/[0-9]+")
if matcher.search(link.get("href")):
    print(link.text)
```

Alternatively, you can just drop the number component, if you're only really looking for links with "/askwiki/questions" in:

```
if "/askwiki/questions" in link.get("href")
    print(link.text)
```

Comment: Thanks. Learnt a lot about re module because of you :)

Answer (score 0):

try something like :

```
for link in links:
     link = link.get("href")
     if link.startswith("/askwiki/questions/"):
         print(link.test)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex (ie what you have, [0-9]+), you have to import the re library. Check out this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) to the documentation on using re to find patterns!